# How to run different child process independently in python?

Tags: python

I have various python function which i intend to run independently. 
For exmaple ,
def graphic()  is responsible for all GUI elements and renders GUI 
def connect()  this function constantly listens and connects to other system

The problem is these 2 functions are not running in parallel. I have used multiprocessing module in python
This is a gist of the code

```
p = Process ( target = graphic() , args = () )      
p1 = Process (target = connect() , args = () )
p.start()
p1.start()
p.join()
p1.join()
```

These 2 functions eventhough are run in different process are not running in parallel. I am only able to connect to systems if i close the GUI. Is there any way i can spawn process parallely, where i can run graphic and connect functions independently ?

Comment: Can you elaborate, please? What behavior do you expect from the code above?  What do you mean "not running in parallel?"

Comment: Basically , graphic function is responsible for the GUI to be rendered , which i have coded using Tkinter. Now the connect function constantly loops and receives connection from various other systems. So here`s what i did. I ran this program and in other terminal fired away from slave systems which intend to connect to this master system. The point is , connection is only happening when i close the GUI i,e terminate the graphic function. Its not like these 2 functions are running independent and parallely.

Comment: Did you try running these two functions directly in separate python processes, just to make sure you're seeing what you're seeing? There could be some kind of resource contention apart from CPU cycles.

Comment: Please **update** the question.  Don't add comments to it.  Please **update** it to be very clear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Possibly because you're calling the functions instead of passing a reference to them? ie, the first two lines should be:

```
p = Process(target=graphic, args=())
p1 = Process(target=connect, args=())
```

Comment: And, strictly speaking, the `args=()` argument isn't necessary.

Comment: Nice catch!  Totally glanced over it!